orapki - how to import a pfx file
I have searched around for the example commands on how to import a pfx file.
I just have a .CER file for the Server and i just have a .PFX file for the private key.
I guess its possible to do this just with orapki commands I hope.
I have done following.

Created a wallet.
imported root.cer
imported intermediate.cer
now when importing the server.cer it asks me to import the private key first / or similar to this.

Expectation: The pfx and then cer file gets imported to my wallet.
